# Alternatives for Apps relying on Parse after shutdown?

Tags: android, ios, web-services

Parse announced that they will be [shutting down](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/) whole Parse service after a year. Can this really happen? And can they take such a decision in such a short notice?

What is the easiest way to migrate to another service? Migrating the database which they say they will make easy is just the small part. What will happen to the client-side codes? And cloud-code? Do other services which use javascript on the server-side differ from cloud-code?

People with Parse related service experience, can you please offer pros and cons of these services keeping in mind we will be porting from Parse

Moreover, how can we be sure the other services that we port to will not be shutdown similarly, as it means this business is not profitable for the companies?

For my specific purpose, We need these musts;

- Push Notifications
- Server-side code (cloud-code)
- iOS and Android Sdks

Comment: They're open sourcing the parse server so you can self-host, take a look at https://parse.com/docs/server/guide#migrating

Comment: @0942v8653 you are right. However, things like the dataBrowser will not be available anymore right? and PushNotifications. My clients used the PushNotifications screen as admins and could easily send Notifications to predefined Groups..

Comment: Could you please list exactly all features that might be needed? Even people who don't know Parse must be able to answer (that's one of the rules of this site). Thanks!

Comment: @aytunch - 'Can they take such a decision on short notice' - be happy they gave any notice at all.

Comment: @aytunch - as to being sure a replacement won't be shut down - if you want to make sure something you depend on is going to be there, you need to somehow control it. Contracts might work, if written correctly. If that's not good enough, then you might have to do it yourself.

Comment: We are currently putting together a proposition to support both our clients and other Parse developers you can find out more information here: http://parsehosting.net/

Comment: @aytunch: It actually sounds like they are in the process of that now: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11084069

Comment: You can use an open source alternative like SocketCluster socketcluster.io for the push notification aspect.

Answer (score 3):

https://backendless.com/ seems like a valid alternative to Parse.

I posted a question on their support forum and it seems they are preparing a blog post and migration guide for their service.

> We are working on it. It is a top priority for us. This includes a blog post and a full blown migration guide.

[link to support question](http://support.backendless.com/topic/migration-guide-for-parse-customers)

[Link to the migration guide](https://backendless.com/parse-to-backendless-migration-guide/)

Answer (score 2):

I do recommend a Parse hosting service like [back4app.](http://www.back4app.com) You can [migrate in less than 5 minutes](http://blog.back4app.com/2016/03/01/quick-wizard-migration/) without re-coding your front-end/app and you have the same UX that you had on Parse.

Comment: Does back4apps have sdks for android and iOS? and what about server side code? also push notification? and lastly I couldn't find pricing on their website?

Comment: About the SDK and Push they are still working on these feature for back4app framework but parse users can still using parse SDK and Push because back4apps will support it. On back4app framework all the code is generated in Node.JS. There's a menu with all the prices. back4app.com/en/pricing

Answer (score 0):

For the requirements you have listed, I would consider [Backendless](https://backendless.com). It offers API support in a variety of SDKs (Android and iOS included). There is support for push notifications and Cloud Code. The server-side code can be written in Java, PHP and Node.JS. There is only one plan and it is free, with it you can get up to 50 API calls/sec, this is something you'd be spending $200/month on Parse.

For full disclosure, I am the company founder.

Comment: You might want to add that you are affiliated with the product.

Answer (score 0):

StrongLoop is one of your options, although you will have to self-host it.
https://strongloop.com/ - has Push, server side code, Android, iOS SDKs

Comment: Parse is making the server open source and it can be selfhosted too. So no need to change to another system if selfhosting is no problem.

Comment: @juergend Can we self host parse in any kind of hosting service? Does it have a special requirement?

Comment: A [first guide is here](https://parse.com/docs/server/guide#migrating). I am sure more will follow